# EmailAddressAttribute without being required

Tags: .net, data-annotations

I have a  `[EmailAddress]` DataAnnotation from .net 4.5 on a model property, which returns a '**The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.**' error during validation, when the Email property is empty.

While this is technically true, I would have expected this empty value to only be caught with a `[Required]` annotation.

Is there any parameter I'm missing which can be passed to the `[EmailAddress]` annotation to allow empty strings to validate, or do I have to fall back to using a custom validator regular expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such parameter for `EmailAddressAttribute`. The validation code for this attibute is following:

```
if (value == null)
{
    return true;
}
string input = value as string;
return ((input != null) && (_regex.Match(input).Length > 0));
```

And the regex is defined as (there will be no match for empty string):

```
_regex = new Regex(@"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

To achieve your goal you can create your can inherit from `DataTypeAttribute` override `IsValid` method, so it will return `true` for empty or null strings and use instance of  `EmailAddressAttribute`. This should be something like this:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    string input = value as string;
    var emailAddressAttribute = new EmailAddressAttribute();

    return (input != null) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || emailAddressAttribute.IsValid(input));
}
```

Comment: *To achieve your goal you can inherit from EmailAddressAttribute* That class is `sealed`. You have to use composition.

Comment: Also `value as string` followed by `IsNullOrEmpty` will treat values that aren't strings as email addresses. E.g. `5.5M` is an email address, according to this implementation of `IsValid`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is good point! And you are totally correct about non-string values. I extended my answer with implementation that takes into account the type of passed parameter.

Comment: `IsString(value)` will never be `true`. `T` is always `object`. You could use `GetType` but that doesn't handle nulls. I think you want something along the lines of: `if (value == null) return true; var valueString = value as string; return valueString != null && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueString) || _emailAddressAttribute.IsValid(valueString));`

Comment: And again you're right. I had to re-read the code at least once before updating the answer :)

Comment: For me it was just a matter of trimming the string, checking if the string is empty, and if it is, change the string to null. Then it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Other way is to just call API differently. 
For JSON ask caller to provide `"Email": null` or don't include this property in the body. For XML ask caller who is providing empty element `<Email></Email>` to remove this element from message body if email is not available.

If JSON property is null or not present or XML element not present, the field in your model becomes null and thus won't throw validation error because is just not present unless you have `[Required]` added. This way you drive required or not.

I do understand in some instances "lazy" or unable caller may want to always send same body with empty value, especially for XML. *"I'm sending this `<Email></Email>` because my customer didn't provide me the email"*